# Floating section hide when Lightbox popup is exists on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm about to hide the right side floating section when Popup exists: https://dev.resiliencelab.us/
So I was trying this jQuery code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if (jQuery('#elementor-popup-modal-2607').css('display') == 'flex') {
    jQuery('.right-floating-for-popup').css('display', 'none');
}
if(jQuery('.eicon-close').click()){
  jQuery('.right-floating-for-popup').css('display', 'block');
}
});
```

But it didn't help. It completely hides the lightbox in the first place. I don't want to  trigger hide show from the "Learn more" button because on the page load when popup shows, It also shold not show the floating section.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just solved this myself :)
Since this was a popup and popup triggering after 3 sec of page load, so I needed to run my jQuery code after 5 sec with the delay function.

Also changed some condition to check the click both close and learn more button. Finally I modified the code and resolved my issue:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(
        function() {
            if (jQuery('#elementor-popup-modal-2607').css('display') == 'flex') {
                jQuery('.right-floating-for-popup').css('display', 'none');
            }


            jQuery(".learn-more").click(function() {
                jQuery(this).data('clicked', true);
                if (jQuery('.learn-more').data('clicked')) {
                    jQuery('.right-floating-for-popup').css('display', 'none');
                }
            });



            jQuery(".eicon-close").click(function() {
                jQuery(this).data('clicked', true);
                if (jQuery('.eicon-close').data('clicked')) {
                    jQuery('.right-floating-for-popup').css('display', 'block');
                }
            });


        }, 3000);

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: The jQuery().click event only fires when the click action happens, so you actually don't to use timer for both click functions. Since it is already loaded in Dom.ready, it will work if you trigger the clicks. Same with check the css style if it's 'flex'. you can check inside of click event -> when a pop up window close or open -> check the css style. (overall -> you don't need a timer to achieve this)